# Mount NAS via terminal

Tags: mount, cifs

I can mount directories on a NAS with the following command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //{IP address}/{directory} /media/{local directory} -o username={username},password{password}
```

Is there a way of mounting the NAS without specifying a directory? I want to be able to backup all folders that appear on the NAS without having to name each one individually.

The code above without the /{direcory} gives me the following error:

mount error(220): Invalid argument

Refer to the mount-cifs(8) manual page (man mount.cifs)

OS: Linux mint

NAS: WD My book

Comment: Related: [How to get a list of Windows's shared folders on Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/287608/how-to-get-list-of-windowss-shared-folders-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the share(s) exported by your NAS include a name (which may not be the actual directory name but an alias). You need it to identifiy the share.